# CCA in feature selection [R]

Tags: r, feature-selection, canonical-correlation

I'm trying to conduct feature selection based on the Canonical Correlation Analysis (CCA). As far as I know, for two given datasets $X$ and $Y$ CCA looks for the linear projections of $X$ and $Y$ such that these projections have maximum correlation. However, when I try a toy example

```
Xdata <- matrix(rnorm(500, 0, 1), nrow = 100, ncol = 5)
ydata <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE, size = 100), nrow = 100, ncol = 1)
cancor(Xdata, ydata)
```

(**y is a vector** - my dependent variable!)

What I get is

```
$xcoef
            [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]        [,5]
[1,] -0.04607990 -0.007282299  0.054530776  0.046346993  0.05906330
[2,] -0.02983822  0.104050676  0.003147818  0.004958621  0.01000734
[3,] -0.07372590 -0.009876187 -0.054922504  0.003110437  0.02521215
[4,] -0.03107835 -0.004163199  0.016455695 -0.080956295  0.02064770
[5,] -0.04953547 -0.006635680  0.026228562  0.014868537 -0.08338718
```

And I have to admit that I don't fully understand what's going on here. My guess is that to get the **first canonical variable** I need to

```
ccaCoefs <- as.matrix(cancor(Xdata, ydata)$xcoef)              
Xdata %*% ccaTE[, 1]
```

And in this fashion

```
ccaCoefs <- as.data.frame(cancor(Xdata, ydata)$xcoef)              
Xdata %*% ccaTE[, c(1,2)]
```

I can get i.e. $2$ canonical variables that *replace* my original variables. Am I right?

Comment: Try cancor(Xdata, ydata)\$\`X\`.

Comment: @user2974951 this doesn't work.